# Finding the date from "2nd Friday of X month"-style input

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I've been working through some puzzles from [exercism.io](http://exercism.io/). Current puzzle asks me to return a `date()` from input that essentially says "The 3rd Friday of December" or "The 1st Monday of October". I'd love to hear some feedback on how to clean this code up:

```
def meetup_day(year, month, weekday, spec_weekday):
    import calendar
    from datetime import date

    last_day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    wkday = {'Monday': 0, 'Tuesday': 1, 'Wednesday': 2, 'Thursday': 3, 'Friday': 4, 'Saturday': 5, 'Sunday': 6}
    schedule_day = wkday[weekday]

    if spec_weekday == "teenth":
        check_range = range(13, 20)
    elif spec_weekday == "last":
        check_range = range(last_day - 6, last_day + 1)
    else:
        spec_weekday = int(spec_weekday[0:1])
        check_range = range(7 * spec_weekday - 6, 7 * spec_weekday + 1)

    for index in check_range:
        if index > last_day:
            break
        if schedule_day == calendar.weekday(year, month, index):
            schedule_day = index

    return date(year, month, schedule_day)

meetup_day(2014, 3, "Friday", "2nd")
meetup_day(2013, 6, "Wednesday", "4th")
meetup_day(2013, 12, "Monday", "1st")
meetup_day(2015, 5, "Tuesday", "teenth")
meetup_day(2015, 4, "Thursday", "last")
```

I'm still fairly new to Python, and `datetime` stuff throws me through a loop. I chose to use `calendar` as well as `date` because I thought the syntax was easier to understand. However, I'm definitely open to ideas on more efficient ways to do this.

Quick note: The "teenth" thing:

> Note that "Monteenth", "Tuesteenth", etc are all made up words. There
>   was a meetup whose members realised that there are exactly 7 days that
>   end in '-teenth'. Therefore, one is guaranteed that each day of the
>   week (Monday, Tuesday, ...) will have exactly one date that is named
>   with '-teenth' in every month.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty clear but can be improved using builtin capabilities of `calendar`: the `monthcalendar` method return a list of list representing each week of the selected month (zeroes are days that are not in the month). By filtering these weeks using the index of the day you are looking for, you get all the possible day of the month that are the requested day. You can then just pick the right one into this list.

Python related remarks:

- Put your import at the beginning of the file, not into functions. It will slow you down if you are heavily calling functions that contain import statements;
- `wkday` is a constant and must be declared as such: outside of the function and with proper case;
- there is no really need to make `wkday` a dictionary given that you can get the same information it holds using `.index` on a list;
- [optional] depending on your needs, you may want to perform proper input validations.

---

```
import calendar
from datetime import date

DAY_NAMES = [day for day in calendar.day_name]

def meetup_day(year, month, weekday, spec_weekday):
    day_index = DAY_NAMES.index(weekday)
    possible_dates = [
        week[day_index]
        for week in calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
        if week[day_index]] # remove zeroes

    if spec_weekday == 'teenth':
        for day_num in possible_dates:
            if 13 <= day_num <= 19:
                return date(year, month, day_num)
    elif spec_weekday == 'last':
        day_index = -1
    elif spec_weekday == 'first':
        day_index = 0
    else:
        day_index = int(spec_weekday[0]) - 1
    return date(year, month, possible_dates[day_index])

meetup_day(2014, 3, "Friday", "2nd")
meetup_day(2013, 6, "Wednesday", "4th")
meetup_day(2013, 12, "Monday", "1st")
meetup_day(2015, 5, "Tuesday", "teenth")
meetup_day(2015, 4, "Thursday", "last")
```

Answer (score 2):

Well my first question is, what's a `spec_weekday`? It can apparently be "2nd", "4th" as well as "teenth" or "last". What can't it be? Well it can't be any string besides "teenth" or "last" that doesn't begin with a number. Not even whitespace apparently. None of this is explicitly told to the user, you don't even raise helpful errors. If I tried to do this:

```
meetup_day(2013, 6, "Sunday", "last Sunday")
```

I get this unhelpful error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    meetup_day(2013, 6, "Sunday", "last Sunday")
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 14, in meetup_day
    spec_weekday = int(spec_weekday[0:1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'l'
```

I can figure out that 'l' is the first letter of my `spec_weekday`, but that requires investigation. Instead, you should have a docstring that explains what can be passed to parameters. Docstrings are programmatically accessible comments that tell users how to interact with your code. It's a good idea to have one in most functions, especially if the execution and arguments are non-obvious.

```
def meetup_day(year, month, weekday, spec_weekday):
    """Returns date object from a wordy description of a date

    Eg. "Last Sunday in November 2013" could be entered with:
    meetup_day(2013, 11, "Sunday", "last")

    spec_weekday can be an ordinal number, like 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.
    or it can be "last" or "teenth"
    """
```

Now, you'd probably want to explain "teenth". As it is, I don't entirely follow it. I was trying to grasp it from just the code but it really didn't make sense, even though I did understand what it did. The requirement to include it is strange enough that you ought to clearly document it.

And when invalid input is entered you should actually respond with a clear message about it, so the user quicker realises their mistake. Something like this:

```
    try:
        spec_weekday = int(spec_weekday[0:1])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("spec_weekday must be 'teenth', 'last' or begin with a number,")
```

Another problem with your input treatment, `' 4th'` would be treated as invalid because of the whitespace. If you just call `strip()` on a string, it will remove all whitespace from the start and end. So even if the user bizarrely threw in spaces, tabs and newlines then you can get the valid input out of it. Likewise for testing against strings, you should call `.lower()` which will reduce all the characters to lowercase.

```
spec_weekday = spec_weekday.strip().lower()
```

With that line at the start, even `"   \n \t TEenTh   "` could be evaluated correctly.

Now, I actually think using a dictionary for your `wkday` is a good idea, but you have to do more to implement it correctly. One strength that a dictionary has is the ability to have multiple keys point to the same value. In your case, you can use it for multiple ways to pass the day value. For example:

```
wkday = {'monday': 0, 'mon': 0,
```

Now it's even easier to pass valid input, and since Python's a forgiving language it's worth following the paradigm. Especially as you could accept other languages or methods of representing days. Note I also made both keys lowercase, I think you should also `strip().lower()` the keys you pass to the dictionary. And again, you could `try except KeyError` to raise a proper `ValueError` about how that's not a recognised day.

It's bizarre that you have a dictionary for days but months must be integers. Why not have another dictionary for months? Likewise, you could make `spec_weekday`'s special values a dictionary. And if the key doesn't exist in that dictionary then you can try calling `int` instead. Also, `int(spec_weekday[0:1])` is the same as `int(spec_weekday[0])` (and also `int(spec_weekday[:1]`)).

And lastly, `weekday` is a confusing term as it means Monday-Friday. Unfortunately the slightly long `day_of_week` is the most clear way to name this, or `day_name` at least, though that's less clear to read.

Comment: I'm with you. The "teenth" this is something I had never heard of before this exercise. It's just supposed to refer to the day of the month that happens to fall in the 'teens' of that month. So... Sunday the 19th (Sunteenth, I guess? Pff) or Monday the 13th. That sort of thing. It's bizarre. 

You make a lot of good points on documentation, error checking, and input validation. I skipped out on it since the exercise didn't require it, but all of that is something I absolutely should be doing regardless. Thanks for the comments!